# TFS: Do not allow branch changes for builds

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I want to allow contributors to kick off a build, but not to specify the branch.  Is that possible to allow Queue builds but not allow the branch choice?

(This is because the build is wired up to a continuous deploy in Release Manager)

Comment: I can't see a way to do this, I think these new vNext build definitions are designed to be used on many branches as opposed to the TFVC and XAML ones that have to have a 1:1 branch mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider setting the **Edit build definition** permission to **Deny** for the users that you don't want to them change the build definition.

[image]